# mIRC Search for multiple words in text file

Tags: regex, irc, mirc

I am trying to search a text file that will return a result if more than one word is found in that line. I don't see this explained in the documentation and I have tried various loops with no success.

What I would like to do is something similar to this:

```
$read(name.txt, s, word1|word2|word3)
```

or even something like this:

```
$read(name.txt, w, word1*|*word2*|*word3)
```

I don't know RegEx that well so I'm assuming this can be done with that but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: As a regex this would be something like `/(.*(word1|word2|word3).*){2,}/` , not sure how this would work in mIRC though.

Comment: that doesn't work in mIRC but I will play around and see if I can convert that to mIRC syntax

Comment: How many `words` are there?

Comment: It can vary, but I want to search for at least 2 words that match in the same line.

Comment: What is what I've been trying to do with loops but haven't really been very successful. Plus, there are ~200,000 lines so it takes a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation in the client self is good but I also recommend this site: http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc. And with your problem there is a nice article : http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/text_files

All the info is taken from there. So credits to wikichip.

```
alias testForString {
  while ($read(file.txt, nw, *test*, $calc($readn + 1))) {
    var %line = $v1
    ; you can add your own words in the regex, seperate them with a pipe (|)
    noop $regex(%line,/(word1|word2|word3|test)/))
    echo -a Amount of results: $regml(0)
  }
}
```

`$readn` is an identifier that returns the line that `$read()` matched. It is used to start searching for the pattern on the next line. Which is in this case `test`.

In the code above, `$readn` starts at 0. We use `$calc()` to start at line 1. Every match `$read()` will start searching on the next line. When no more matches are after the line specified `$read` will return `$null` - terminating the loop.

The `w` switch is used to use a wildcard in your search

The `n` switch prevents evaluating the text it reads as if it was mSL code. In almost **EVERY** case you must use the n switch. Except if you really need it. Improper use of the $read() identifier without the 'n' switch could leave your script highly vulnerable.

The result is stored in a variable named `%line` to use it later in case you need it.

After that we use a `noop` to execute a regex to match your needs. In this case  you can use `$regml(0)` to find the *amount* of matches which are specified in your regex search. Using an if-statement you can see if there are two or more matches.

Hope you find this helpful, if there's anything unclear, I will try to explain it better.

**EDIT**

@cp022 
I can't comment, so I'll post my comment here, so how does that help in any way to read content from a text file?

Comment: Wow my bad didn't read read from file only read 'check for multiple words'. Will remove my answer ASAP Thanks for the correction .