# Read entire line $nick found on

Tags: irc, mirc

Below I have wrote my basic goal and the code I already have, any help is much appreciated as I am learning myself how IRC Scripting works, thanks guys!

```
on $*:text:*test*:#: { 
  if ($date isin $read(test1.txt, 1)) {
    if ($nick isin $read(test1.txt, 1)) { write test.txt "entire line $nick was found on in test1.txt" $1- }
 }
}
```

Comment: You must clarify specifically what you're trying to achieve! Simply putting the code and ask for our help will not cut it, we need to understand what is the expected behavior you want to accomplish.

Comment: @OrelEraki For me it's pretty clear what he's trying to achieve by reading his 'pseudo-code'

Comment: @Denny, I bet the difference, for number of reasons.

Comment: @Denny, A. The author is a mSL beginner, this means the `pseudo-code` may not be ever what he intended or need, because of accuracy. A beginner can explain what he tries to do by using the common language of English, and not in other language. B. A post text should not work on the assumption of (paraprashing) "see my goal in the code and please help" which is basically what he done, instead of explaining us what he tries to do. In Stackoverflow, we should help by given what the author tries to accomplish, every exemption of description for a question, is bad for all of us.

Comment: @OrelEraki Fair enough, I guess you're right

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you should make your question clearer.

Your question looks like this one [mIRC Search for multiple words in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543839/mirc-search-for-multiple-words-in-text-file/36568985), you can read my answer there for more information, it's mostly the same so I'm copying and pasting it here with edits for your case.

To read a .txt file line by line you need a loop. To use this loop type: `/findNick <NICK>`

```
alias findNick {
  var %nick = $1
  while ($read(test1.txt, nw, $+(*,$date,*), $calc($readn + 1))) {
    var %line = $v1
    if (%nick isin %line) {
      echo -a %nick found on the line: %line
      ; do your stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

`$readn` is an identifier that returns the line that `$read()` matched. It is used to start searching for the pattern on the next line. Which is in this case `$date`. The asteriks means a wildcard, so anything that contains that date.

In the code above, `$readn` starts at 0. We use `$calc()` to start at line 1. Every match `$read()` will start searching on the next line. When no more matches are after the line specified `$read` will return `$null` - terminating the loop.

The `w` switch is used to use a wildcard in your search

The `n` switch prevents evaluating the text it reads as if it was mSL code. In almost **EVERY** case you must use the n switch. Except if you really need it. Improper use of the $read() identifier without the 'n' switch could leave your script highly vulnerable.

The result is stored in a variable named `%line` to use it again to check wheter `$nick` is in the found line. If the `$nick` was found, it will echo the result in your active window.

And again, if there's anything unclear, I will try to explain it better.